# Why is $f(z) = \sum_{n\geq 0} |z|^n \hat f(n) e^{in\theta}$ for $f$ holomorphic on the unit disk?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

I was recently reading a paper and in one of the proofs the author makes the following step where $D = \{ z \in \mathbb C : |z|<1 \}$ denotes the unit disk:

Since $f$ is holomorphic on $D$ and $f \in C^\infty( \overline D)$, the real part of $f$ is harmonic and further
$$
f(z) = \sum_{n\geq 0} |z|^n \hat f(n) e^{in\theta}
$$
for $z=|z|e^{i\theta} \in D$.

It seems like that this is come kind of Fourier expansion of $f$ but I don't see how to come up with this formula (Fourier series go over all intergers not only the non-negative ones right?). Could someone help me?

Comment: $f(z) = \sum_{n\geq 0} |z|^n \hat f(n) e^{in\theta} =\sum_{n\geq 0} \hat f(n)z^n  $, If f is representable by power series in open set $\Omega$, f is holomorphic in $\Omega$

Comment: so the non-negative fourier coefficients are always the taylor coefficients in this case?

Comment: The fourier coefficients are the coefficients of the Laurent series for $f$ about the origin. When $f$ has a pole or essential singularity at $0$, you get coefficients for both positive and negative $n$. But this $f$ is holomorphic at $0$, so all the coefficients for $n < 0$ are $0$, and the Laurent series is the same thing as the Taylor series.